# How to create 2 separate CSS files [theme and components] after building process in Vuepress

Tags: css, vue.js, vuepress

Currently, I am importing custom styles via the enhanceApp.js file (code below), but after the building process (docs:build) of the website, my custom styles are merged with native Vuepress styles. How to create 2 separate CSS files and add them to a project in order which we want eg. on the first place theme styles should be loaded and next custom styles.

```
import '../sass/index.scss';

export default ({ Vue, options, router, siteData }) => {};
```